# Pandas: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, pandas, import

When I try to import pandas into Python I get this error:

```
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/robertdefilippi/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "/Users/robertdefilippi/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
  File "/Users/robertdefilippi/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "/Users/robertdefilippi/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 41, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "/Users/robertdefilippi/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2909, in <module>
    import pandas.tools.plotting as _gfx
  File "/Users/robertdefilippi/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 135, in <module>
    if _mpl_ge_1_5_0():
  File "/Users/robertdefilippi/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 130, in _mpl_ge_1_5_0
    return (matplotlib.__version__  >= LooseVersion('1.5')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

But when I check if pandas is installed:

```
me$ conda install pandas
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .....................
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /Users/me/miniconda2:
#
pandas                    0.17.1              np110py27_0
```

So I don't know what is wrong? What is going on with my pandas?

**Edit**

```
$ pip list |grep matplotlib
$ conda list matplotlib
# packages in environment at /Users/me/miniconda2:
#
matplotlib                1.5.0               np110py27_0
```

For some reason there was no output to `pip list |grep matplotlib`

**Edit2**

I wanted to see if there was a different path to the executables `ipython` and `python`. So I ran this:

```
$ python
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.executable 
/Users/me/miniconda2/bin/python
```

However in IPython, I get this:

```
$ ipython notebook
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.executable
/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
```

Could that be the problem?

Comment: @cel removed, thanks

Comment: Please consider adding the output of `pip list |grep matplotlib` and `conda list matplotlib` to your question.

Comment: I've update the question with your request @cel

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove (or rename) the file `matplotlib.py` from your current working directory. It shadows the real library with the same name.

Comment: remove it from "/Users/me/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/..." ?

Comment: I do not have a matplotlib.py in my working dir... What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat Do you have exactly the same exception as given in the question? If not, you might need a different solution.

Comment: Not exactly, I guess this has happened for a different reason. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me

```
pip install pyparsing==2.4.7
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution，delete your `__init__.pyc` and `__init__.py` files in your project dictionary. because i encounter the problem too，I have been solve it perfectly use this method.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

> Remove (or rename) the file matplotlib.py from your current working directory. It shadows the real library with the same name.

Did not have matplotlib.py in my project.

Still had this error:

```
    >>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import (  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 115, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 84, in <module>
    import pandas.plotting
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from pandas.plotting._core import (
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 17, in <module>
    import pandas.plotting._matplotlib  # noqa
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pandas.plotting._matplotlib.boxplot import (
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\boxplot.py", line 4, in <module>
    from matplotlib.artist import setp
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 28, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\fontconfig_pattern.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pyparsing import (Literal, ZeroOrMore, Optional, Regex, StringEnd,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyparsing\__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    __version__ = __version_info__.__version__
AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

I uninstalled matplotlib which solved the problem for me. Since in the current project I did not use them.

I created a new Python 3.8 environment for the other project that uses matplotlib. This worked as well.

At some point I needed matplotlib in Python 3.6 so i reinstalled it. The error again occurred.

I assume matplotlib does not install pyparsing along with it in Python 3.6 environment.

> pip install pyparsing==2.4.7

This did the trick for me.

Comment: Uninstall matplotlib, while OP accidentally had a py file named matplotlib they shouldn't have named like that, doesn't this solution seem a bit harsch?